# splitting tagged and untagged traffic to bridges on KVM

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, rhel7

I am using RHEL 7.3 KVM 
I have one interface that has both tagged and untagged traffic.

I am looking to split the traffic to 2 bridges. 
so untagged traffic goes to br0 and tagged will go to br0:XX.
br0 goes to a a RHEL server, br0.XX goes to a switch.

What I think is happening when I set these up is the bridge defaults to sending all traffic tagged or untagged to br0.

how is it possible to configure br0 and br0.XX on the KVM to allow for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is tag the interface, so you have eth0 (or bond0) connected to br0; eth0.XX connected to brXX; eth0.YY connected to brYY etc. Then connect the VMs to the right bridges of course